# Plotly Dash center dcc.Input text field

Tags: python, user-input, centering, plotly-dash

I'm having a lot of difficulties figuring out what style parameters are required to center a `dash_core_components.Input` text field in the middle of my page.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

text_input_style = {'justify-content': 'center', 'align-items': 'center'}
bucket_select = html.Div([
    html.Label('S3 bucket:'),
    dcc.Input(id='bucket_name', placeholder='Enter input here...', 
              value=None, type='text', 
              style={'width': '10%', 'textAlign': 'center'}),
    html.Div(id='bucket_out')
], style=text_input_style)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(bucket_select)
app.run_server(port=5555)
```

So far I've tried:

- `'justify-content': 'center'`
- `'align-items': 'center'`
- `'display': 'flex'`
- `'padding-left':'45%'`

I've tried searching the documentation for `dcc.Input`, but I can't find any `style` information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is where](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/input) you can find the various props for `dcc.Input`. You can set the containing `div` to have `display='flex'` and `justifyContent='center'`. Example:

```py
html.Div(
    children=[dcc.Input()],  # fill out your Input however you need
    style=dict(display='flex', justifyContent='center')
)
```

Comment: Worked, thanks! Looks like the `justify-content` I copy/pasted from another site was wrong.