# Centering a dcc.input field in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to center a dcc.input text field to the middle of the screen, however the solutions found here: [Plotly Dash center dcc.Input text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367419/plotly-dash-center-dcc-input-text-field) nor the https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/input page has proven to fix the problem.
My code is:

```py
dcc.Input(
                id="textsearch",
                placeholder='Write your lyrics here and press ENTER...',
                type='text',
                value=None,
                debounce=True,
                style={'width': '20%',"display":"flex", "justifyContent":'center'}
                ),
```

Ive tried the `'textAlign':'center'` as well which works for the html.H6 element above the input bar. Any ideas? See the picture below for reference for what exactly i would like to happen. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying style on the wrong component. You need to apply that to your Input's parent div.

```py
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            children=[
                dcc.Input(
                    id="textsearch",
                    placeholder="Write your lyrics here and press ENTER...",
                    type="text",
                    value="",
                    debounce=True,
                )
            ],
            style={"display": "flex", "justifyContent": "center"},
        )
    ]
)
```

Also, it's advised to pass `""` to your Input if you want it to be empty.